# 406 (NotAcceptable) response from PATCH request in EntitySetController. Web API 2.1. OData

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am very much puzzled and hope somebody can shed any light. After upgrading to the latest version of Web API (from Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.xxx 5.0.0. to Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.xxx 5.1.2) OData's EntitySetController stopped processing PATCH verbs and returns 406 (Not Acceptable) code instead.

The implementation hasn't changed:

```cs
public class ODataAnnouncementController : EntitySetController<TEntity, TKey> where TEntity : class
{
    (...)

    protected override Announcement PatchEntity(Guid key, Delta<Announcement> patch)
    {
        var announcement = getEntityByKeyOrThrowException(key);
        patch.Patch(announcement);
        AnnouncementManager.Instance.Save(announcement, true);
        return announcement;
    }
}
```

The request hasn't changed either:

> Accept: application/json
>
> Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>
> PATCH: http://{url}/odata/Announcement(guid'62E34FB3-A37E-413F-9843-642D95BA580A')
>
> {"Description":"Patched description from Unit Test"}

Breakpoint inside the method is not being hit as if "Delta<Announcement>> patch" has never deserialized. The only condition under which it actually does hit the breakpoint inside the method is when a request BODY is empty resulting with patch object being null of course.

All other verbs (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) work OK.

This used to work before. Is anybody aware of any breaking changes for Web API 2.1 in regards to PATCH? How else could I troubleshoot it?

Thank you so much

Bill

**UPDATE**

Here is the C# model:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class Announcement
{                       
    private Guid _announcementID;
    private string _description;
    private bool _isPrivate;
    private DateTime _createdTime;
    private Nullable<Guid> _membershipID;

    [DataMember]
    public Guid AnnouncementID
    {
        get { return this._announcementID; }
        set { this._announcementID = value; }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string Description
    {
        get { return this._description; }
        set { this._description = value; }
    }       
    [DataMember]
    public bool IsPrivate
    {
        get { return this._isPrivate; }
        set { this._isPrivate = value; }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime CreatedTime
    {
        get { return this._createdTime; }
        set { this._createdTime = value; }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<Guid> MembershipID
    {
        get { return this._membershipID; }
        set { this._membershipID = value; }
    }
}
```

I use explicit data model:

```cs
var routingConventions = ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefault();
config.Routes.MapODataRoute(
            routeName: "ODataRoute",
            routePrefix: "odata",
            model: BuildExplicitODataModel(),
            pathHandler: new DefaultODataPathHandler(),
            routingConventions: routingConventions  
        );

public static IEdmModel BuildExplicitODataModel()
{
ODataModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ODataModelBuilder();
var announcementSet = buildAnnouncementModel(modelBuilder);
return modelBuilder.GetEdmModel();
}

private static EntitySetConfiguration<Announcement> buildAnnouncementModel(ODataModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        var announcementSet = modelBuilder.EntitySet<Announcement>("Announcement");
        announcementSet.HasEditLink(
            entityContext => entityContext.Url.ODataLink(
                new EntitySetPathSegment(entityContext.EntitySet.Name),
                new KeyValuePathSegment(ODataUriUtils.ConvertToUriLiteral(entityContext.EntityInstance.AnnouncementID, ODataVersion.V3))),
            followsConventions: true);

        announcementSet.HasIdLink(
            entityContext => entityContext.Url.ODataLink(
                new EntitySetPathSegment(entityContext.EntitySet.Name),
                new KeyValuePathSegment(ODataUriUtils.ConvertToUriLiteral(entityContext.EntityInstance.AnnouncementID, ODataVersion.V3))),
                followsConventions: true);

        var announcement = announcementSet.EntityType;
        announcement.HasKey(p => p.AnnouncementID);
        announcement.Property(p => p.Description);
        announcement.Property(p => p.IsPrivate);
        announcement.Property(p => p.CreatedTime);
        announcement.Property(p => p.MembershipID);
        return announcementSet;
}
```

Here is request payload:

> PATCH http://{url}/odata/Announcement(guid'62E34FB3-A37E-413F-9843-642D95BA580A')
>   Accept: application/json
>   Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

BODY:

> {"Description":"Patched description from Unit Test"}

Answer (score 0):

After I checked the latest file EntityRoutingConvention.cs, 
I found that the actionName can only be Patch or PatchAnnouncement.

The PatchEntity is never called.

Can you try renaming the method with Patch or PatchAnnouncement?

---

**UPDATE**

However it works fine in my repro project.
Can you compare your reference version, WebApiConfig.cs, AnnouncementsController.cs and request with mine.

I notice some difference:

1. The controller name is ODataAnnouncementController, do you use "ODataAnnouncement" as the entittyset name in the model builder?
2. In your PATCH request, why use "Announcement" rather than "Announcements"?

**Reference**

Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi 5.1.2
targetFramework="net45"

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.OData.Builder;
using ReproPatchNotWork.Models;

namespace ReproPatchNotWork
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            builder.EntitySet<Announcement>("Announcements");
            config.Routes.MapODataRoute("odata", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel());
        }
    }
}
```

**AnnouncementsController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Web.Http.OData;

namespace ReproPatchNotWork.Models
{
    public class AnnouncementsController : EntitySetController<Announcement, Guid>
    {
        protected override Announcement PatchEntity(Guid key, Delta<Announcement> patch)
        {
            Announcement announcement = new Announcement();
            patch.Patch(announcement);
            return announcement;
        }
    }
}
```

**Request**

PATCH http://{url}/odata/Announcements(guid'62E34FB3-A37E-413F-9843-642D95BA580A')

Accept: application/json

Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

Body: {"Description":"Patched description from Unit Test"}

Comment: Thank you Feng for your suggestions. I have tried them both and unfortunately neither Patch nor PatchAnnouncement worked. Please note both Patch and PatchEntity are defined in the base class which I properly override.  Very strange. Must be some kind of breaking behavior with new version.

Comment: Can you share the definition of Announcement and entire request payload? So I can repro the issue.

Comment: Hi Feng. I've updated my question with the code you had asked for.

Comment: However Patch works fine in my project. Please check my answer update.

Comment: Thank you very much Feng for taking a look at this. I use explicit OData model (I need to because some of my entities have relations that cannot be described by OData conventions).

Comment: I tried your model and found the problem is with your controller name. It will work if you rename your controller from ODataAnnouncementController to AnnouncementController.

Comment: Hi Feng. Sorry for the late reply. I did not have an access to my code for a while. I'm afraid that would not be a solution in my case. This is an excerpt from larger code base obviously and I did some slight simplifications. My real AnnouncementController derives from ODataAnnouncementController as of: _public class AnnouncementController : ODataAnnouncementController { .. }_

Comment: We have considerable amount of unit tests that 'guard' all the web api functionality for all models. Announcements is just one of them. The point is - after the upgrade mentioned in my initial description they immediately revealed the 406 problem for all of our models and only when doing a PATCH. All other verbs work correctly. I'm not sure how else I could simplify the problem to get it reproduced. I was hoping somebody would have surely encountered the similar 406 response problem already. I sincerely appreciate you even trying to reproduce it on your own.